# What's the difference between object.function and object.function() in python3?

Tags: python, function, object, methods

Admission: in python, I sometimes forget to include the `()` when I'm calling a method, so I accidentally use `object.method` instead of `object.method()`.

The error I get often appears to indicate that my `object.method` call has returned the method itself, instead of calling the method. I'm wondering if this means that by using `object.method` or perhaps just `function` you can pass functions/methods around as arguments?

**Bonus:** If so, what are some applications of this? I know, for example, that lambdas can be used to pass anonymous functions as parameters.

Comment: functions are objects in python so `object.function` returns the function object, without calling it

Comment: Asking for possible applications of a technique is a bit too broad. But here's one anyway: `list.sort(key=function_name_goes_here)`.

Answer (score 2):

It returns a function object that you could use later. For example

```
def myPrint(fun):
    for i in range(5):
        print(fun(i))

def myFactorial(x):
    acc = 1
    for i in range(1,x):
        acc *= i
    return acc
```

Then you can do

```
>>> myPrint(myFactorial)
1
1
2
6
24
```

Or

```
>>> myPrint(range)
[]
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

This allows you to create a function that you want to use in other context (And it's pretty common in python), lot of built-in functions do this, like `map`, `filter`, `reduce`, `sort`...

As you can see `myObject.myFunction` returns the function itself while `myObject.myFunction()` actually "executes" it

Comment: Thanks! I'm now trying to figure out how in the `myPrint(myFactorial)` call, `myFactorial` determines it's parameter `x` in order to print `1 1 2 6 24`. How does that work?

Comment: It's the `i` in the for loop, when it calls `print(fun(i))`

Comment: I see, and where is `fun()` defined, or does it not have to be for some reason?? Or should that be `fun[i]`?

Comment: `fun` inside `myPrint` is any function you pass as argument, the definition is wherever the function you pass is defined :). If you call it like `myPrint(myObject.myFunction)` it's defined inside `myObject`

Answer (score 0):

It is used for so called callbacks. YOu can pass the function as argument and after you have done your magic in the function call the callback. Usefull if you do async stuff.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand. Could you provide a link or a simpler explanation?

Comment: Hm an example would be you have a function which calls an url, which is async. You want that something happens when the call to an url is finished and you got a result. In this case you could pass a callback to the function which calls the url. This callback is than called from the url function when its call is completed. Don't know if it's now explained a bit more simple. Are you working with javascript? JQuery uses callbacks very much.

Comment: callbacks aren't the only use for this. It's a general feature of the language.

Comment: @Daenyth He asked for an example where you could need it. Callbacks is an example.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. `object.method` returns the method as an object.